# Django Crispy forms - inline Formsets 'ManagementForm data' error with update view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

Good Evening,

Im having trouble with a crispy forms inlineformset. I have followed guides as per:

https://github.com/timhughes/django-cbv-inline-formset/blob/master/music/views.py
https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crispy_tag_formsets.html#formsets

**EDIT**
I think the issue is something to do with the dual submit buttons. the devicemodel form has a button that when pressed produces this error. but there is also a save button as part of the resource helper, when that's submitted I get an empty model form error.

I've added screenshots of what happens when you action each button

[image: Error when resource save button pressed]

[image: error when update device button is pressed]

and I must be missing something as am getting the error:

```
['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']
```

here is my update view:

```
class EditDeviceModel(PermissionRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = DeviceModel
    form_class = DeviceModelForm

    template_name = "app_settings/base_formset.html"
    permission_required = 'config.change_devicemodel'
    success_message = 'Device  Type "%(model)s" saved successfully'

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):         
        return '{}#device_models'.format(reverse("config:config_settings"))

    def get_success_message(self, cleaned_data):
        return self.success_message % dict(
            cleaned_data,
            model=self.object.model,
        )     

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title']='Edit Device Model'
        if self.request.POST:
            context['formset'] = DeviceFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
        else:
            context['formset'] = DeviceFormSet(instance=self.object)
        context['helper'] = DeviceFormSetHelper()
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        formset = context['formset']
        if formset.is_valid():
            self.object = form.save()
            formset.instance = self.object
            formset.save()
            return redirect(self.success_url)
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

Here are my forms:

```
class MonitoredResourceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MonitoredResource
        fields = ['resource','model']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.is_add = kwargs.pop("is_add", False)
        super(MonitoredResourceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_id = 'snmp_resource_form'
        self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(    
                Div(
                    Field('model'),
                    Field('resource', placeholder="Resource"),
                    css_class='col-lg-3'
                ),
            css_class='row'
            ),
            Div(
                Div(
                    HTML("""<input type="submit" name="submit" value="""),
                    HTML('"Add' if self.is_add else '"Update' ),
                    HTML(""" monitored resource" class="btn btn-primary"/>"""),
                    HTML("""<a href="{% url 'config:config_settings' %}#monitored_resources" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</a>"""),
                    HTML("""{% if object %}
                            <a href="{% url 'config:delete_monitoredresource' object.id %}"
                            class="btn btn-danger">
                            Delete <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            {% endif %}"""),
                    css_class='col-lg-12'
                    ),
                css_class='row'
                ),
        ) 

class DeviceModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DeviceModel
        fields = ['model','vendor','device_type','ports','uplink_speed']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.is_add = kwargs.pop("is_add", False)
        super(DeviceModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_id = 'device_type_form'
        self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(    
                Div(
                    Field('model', placeholder="Model"),
                    Field('vendor',),
                    Field('device_type',),
                    Field('ports', placeholder="Ports"),
                    Field('uplink_speed', placeholder="Uplink Speed"),
                    css_class='col-lg-6'
                ),
            css_class='row'
            ),
            Div(
                Div(
                    HTML("""<input type="submit" name="submit" value="""),
                    HTML('"Add' if self.is_add else '"Update' ),
                    HTML(""" Device Model" class="btn btn-primary"/>"""),
                    HTML("""<a href="{% url 'config:config_settings' %}#device_models" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</a>"""),
                    HTML("""{% if object %}
                            <a href="{% url 'config:delete_device_model' object.id %}"
                            class="btn btn-danger">
                            Delete <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            {% endif %}"""),
                    css_class='col-lg-12'
                    ),
                css_class='row'
                ),
        )

DeviceFormSet = inlineformset_factory(DeviceModel, MonitoredResource, form=MonitoredResourceForm, extra=1)

class DeviceFormSetHelper(FormHelper):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DeviceFormSetHelper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.form_method = 'post'
        self.render_required_fields = True
        self.form_id = 'snmp_resource_form'
        self.form_method = 'POST'
        self.add_input(Submit("submit", "Save"))
        self.layout = Layout(
            Div(    
                Div(
                    Field('model'),
                    Field('resource', placeholder="Resource"),
                    css_class='col-lg-6'
                ),
            css_class='row'
            ),
        )
```

and in the templates I render:

```
{% block content %} 
{% include "home/form_errors.html" %}
<div class="col-lg-6">
    {% crispy form %}
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
    {% crispy formset helper %}
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
{% endblock %}
```

is anyone able to see what im missing?

Comment: share your project code in zip somewhere if you can.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to render management form in your template, [explained here why you need that](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform)

Management Form is used by the formset to manage the collection of forms contained in the formset. If you don’t provide this management data, an exception will be raised

add this in view html

```
{{ DeviceFormSet.management_form }}
```

Comment: how do I fix my current issue? I tried adding {{ formset.management_form }} to the template but it hasn't worked

Comment: ive aded my DeviceForm and MonitoredResourceForm, I think it may be something to do with it creating seperate forms and submits for each model maybe?

Comment: can you share the version of Django you are using ?

Comment: im using version 1.11.9

Comment: @AlexW have you added it like {{ DeviceFormSet.management_form }} same in template ? if not please try to add it as per the update answer.

Comment: if you have added {{ formset.management_form }} replace it with {{ DeviceFormSet.management_form }} as per your formset name.

Comment: nope same issues, the formset is being passed as formeset in the context context['formset'] = DeviceFormSet(self.request.POST, instance=self.object).
im pretty sure its something to do with the relationship between the two models. when I hit the update device button which is part of the DeviceFOrm I get that error, when I hit save from the resource helper I get an empty device model error

Comment: all of the code used for this is in the question, I have also added pictures of the errors now

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a  tag and also {{format.management_form|crispy}}
I guess

Comment: Also is always nice to include a Form tag with post method to parent form.and management form is must

Comment: what tag? from what I understand from the crispy docs its correct?
https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crispy_tag_formsets.html#formsets

Comment: ive aded my DeviceForm and MonitoredResourceForm, I think it may be something to do with it creating seperate forms and submits for each model maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that each form in a formset has its own `management_form`.  I haven't dealt with this specifically in crispy, but in the general formsets, that was the problem that I had.  You have to manually spell out each piece of the formset, either by iteration or hardcoding, and make sure that each has its `management_form`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the answer in the [documentation](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crispy_tag_formsets.html):

```
{{ formset.management_form|crispy }}
{% for form in formset %}
    {% crispy form %}
{% endfor %}
```